# Unicode only displays \u>0100

Tags: java, windows, unicode, intellij-idea

I am attempting to get a `unicode` symbol ("⁔"/unicode 2054) to print out of my IDE's log.
When I run `System.out.println("\u2054");`, it responds with "?".
When I run any unicode greater than 00FF, it also results in "?".
I am running windows, my IDE is intellij, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any future or present people with the same (or similar) problem:
The solution was in the file encoding at the bottom right of UI (It was windows default rather than UTF-8). Apologies for being stupid before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a `?` (or the more stylized question mark � for unicode) as the [replacement character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm). It's used when there's no proper character to display. This can be due to missing glyphs or encoding problems.

Apparently in this case it was the case of trying to write unicode characters with non-unicode encoding, so those that couldn't be mapped would be converted to the replacement character `?` (the non-unicode replacement character).

Comment: I can Ctr-V any of the text into the log, but cannot get it to write it, So I'm pretty sure the font is not the problem...

Comment: @NMorris Then you've got an encoding problem, most likely due to Windows. Perhaps take a look at the console settings.